# Jordan blocks and the bases

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Find the Jordan canonical form and a Jordan basis for the given matrix :
$
\left[{\begin{array}{l}
{{4}\hspace{0.33em}{0}\hspace{0.33em}{0}}\\
{{2}\hspace{0.33em}{1}\hspace{0.33em}{3}}\\
{{5}\hspace{0.33em}{0}\hspace{0.33em}{4}}
\end{array}}\right]
$

Comment: You could not have put in less effort it this question

Answer (score 0):

The Jordan Canonical Form is given by $\begin{pmatrix} 4&&1&&0\\0&&4&&0\\0&&0&&1\end{pmatrix}$. This is obtained by observing that the characteristic polynimial is $(x-4)^2(x-1)$ and $4$ has a geometric multiplicity of $1$. A Jordan Basis is obtained by the method of [generalized eigenvectors](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Emoose/240S2013/slides7-31.pdf), or, by first plugging in eigenvectors for 4 and 1 and then picking a linearly independent so as to complete the basis by solving the matrix equation for one of the vectors, as done [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Ejlindquist/115B/JCFBases.pdf). Yet another method is to solve the matrix equation $AM=MJ$, where $A$ is the given matrix, $J$ is the Jordan normal form given above, and $M$ is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&&a&&0\\1&&b&&0\\1&&c&&1\end{pmatrix}$; where $a,b,c$ are to be solved and the first and last columns are the eigenvectors corresponding to $4$ and $1$ respectively. The result of doing the last procedure is $\displaystyle{\left[(0,1,1),(0.2,0,0.2),(0,0,1)\right]}$

Comment: Thanks a lot can you tell me how we can find a basis for it

Comment: Hello can you tell me

Comment: @user401187 I hope its clear!

Comment: Thanks a lot yes it is clear nowww .sorry 